# how to convert string to datetime MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, type-conversion

I am using Ms Access and below is my Query

```
select * from travelapproval 
where CDate(datefrom1) <=  Date() 
and CDate(dateto1) >= Date()
```

I am using datefrom1 and dateto1 are text type. It shows `"Data type mismatch in criteria expression."`

How can I convert them to datetime even I tried with CDate function.

[image]

Comment: Can you show a couple of sample rows?

Comment: I have attach the image of my MS Access table.

Comment: Silly question; why would you want to store dates as text??  Why not just change the data type to DateTime and be done with it?

Comment: I know that this is an old thread, but one important factor is that when looking at a swath of dates, it's much easier to compare them when they are of the form YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM.  All subfields are the same width, and the most significant subfields are to the left.

Answer (score 5):

*Assuming that you are not able to change the field type to Date.*

Check whether you have non date values in datefrom1 and dateto1 fields.

If you do, use the following to get around it:

```
CDate(IIf(IsDate([StringDate]),[StringDate],0))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

```
  SELECT * from travelapproval
  WHERE Format(datefrom1, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss am/pm") <=  Date() 
  AND Format(dateto1, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss am/pm") >=  Date()
```

you can find more example and explanations [here](http://webcheatsheet.com/SQL/access_functions/format.php)

Comment: shows error ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Format(datefrom1, mm/dd/yyyy hh:hh:ss) <= Date() AND Format(dateto1, mm/dd/yyyy hh:hh:ss) >= Date().

Comment: this is my new code as you suggested.  string strSql = "SELECT * from travelapproval  WHERE Format(datefrom1, mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss am/pm) <=  Date()   AND Format(dateto1, mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss am/pm) >=  Date()  and approval=?";

Comment: take a look here how it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263766/convert-a-text-to-a-datetime-in-access?rq=1

Comment: if I do like this  string strSql = "SELECT * from travelapproval  WHERE datefrom1 <=  Date() AND dateto1 >=  Date()";  yes it is showing records but ALL. not satisfying the below condition

datefrom1 <=  Date() AND dateto1 >=  Date()

Comment: Is it just me, or are you missing the quotes for the date format?  It's a string, afterall.

Comment: Doesn't Date() not return the time? AFAIK, if you want both time and date, you use Now()

Comment: `Format` returns a string from a date or number. The question is about the opposite

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the datetime string is from SQL Server with milliseconds,

```
Format(Replace([SQLSERVER_DATESTRING],".000",""),"mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss am/pm")
```